# Server Manager 2012 shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2012

What is the shortcut (after bringing up the windows Run box, Windows-R) for starting the Server Manager?

To be clear I am referring to this dialog (on win 2012)

[image]

This is the dialog that comes up when you click 'Manage' when right clicking on 'This PC' in a Windows explorer window:

[image]

What I have tried already:

compmgmt.msc  (not the correct dialog)

appwiz.cpl    (still requires another click to bring up the dialog)

[this article from microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731774.aspx) (refers only to 'server manager' command line shortcuts)

Comment: Ironically I have the opposite issue, I want it to do exactly the opposite to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself, it's "servermanager". Here is a list of the most common ones:

- Group Policy Management: gpmc.msc
- Server Manager: servermanager
- Services: services.msc
- Windows Firewall with Advanced Security: wf
- Active Directory Users & Computers: dsa.msc
- Active Directory Administrative Center: dsac.exe
- Active Directory Domains and Trusts: domain.msc
- Active Directory Sites and Services: dssite.msc
- Certificate Authority: certsrv.msc
- DNS Management: dnsmgmt.msc
- DHCP Management: dhcpmgmt.msc
- Windows Server Backup: wbadmin